# CSS DIV Layout (keeping a floating DIV from dropping below another div when a window is narrowed)

Tags: css

I have a layout template made to have a top banner, a left side menu and a content area to the right of the menu.  I'm trying to figure out how to keep the 'application_layout_content' div from dropping below the 'application_layout_menu' if the browser window is narrowed. I'm not sure if I was doing this the right way to begin with; otherwise it seems to work fine.

(looking at IE7/IE8 mainly), I've played around with 'overflow' and 'position' properties but either will cause problems in one version or the other.   Like 'Overflow:  auto' will work in IE7 (main content div won't drop below the menu div), but in IE8 it will cause a greyed out vertical scrollbar and the main content div will still drop below the menu div.

Thanks!

```
#application_layout_header
{
    background-image: url('../hHeader.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 103px;
}
#application_layout_menu
{
    width: 205px;
    float: left;
}
#application_layout_content
{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish this as long as you have a fixed width defined for #application_layout_menu. Try making it a percentage value.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  It's over my head a little though.   If I give the menu div a % width and the content div a % width, it's closer to working but with some undesired affects, like the content moving away from the menu as the window gets bigger or moving underneath the menu if the window gets really small.   I've been playing around with FLOAT, CLEAR, and POSITION on both divs but haven't got it yet.    Maybe I should put both of those divs in a single "body" div?    Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, in that case, your original solution is fine as long as you can live with a minimum width. What I mean is, you should assume that the user won't resize his browser to unrealistic dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

try setting a min-width on #application_layout_header